# Unable to execute Oracle Select Stmt

Tags: sql, oracle

Have updated the question with suggested change and new error encountered,
I'm executing this code

```
SELECT
    b.*, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DOJ <= current_date 
                    AND (DOL IS NULL OR DOL >= current_date) 
                  THEN ID END) FIRST 
FROM
    (
     select ID,max(case when a.massn in('00','A1') then a.begda end) as DOJ,
     max(case when a.massn in ('A4') then a.begda end) as DOP,      
     max(case when a.massn in ('A3','A5') then a.begda end) as DOT,       
     max(case when a.massn='A6' then a.begda end) dol,
     max(case when a.massn in ('A6') then a.aedtm end) as changed_on_date,     
     max(case when a.massn in ('A6') then massn end) as massn,
     max(case when a.massn in ('A6') then massg end) as massg 
    from "Table"."T1" a 
     group by ID
  )b
  WHERE FIRST = 1
```

I'm getting an error:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
> 01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
> *Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
> the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
> "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
> with no extra whitespace.
> *Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: what table(s) are you trying to query?

Comment: `FIRST` is a function in Oracle (a reserved keyword) but here you are trying to use that as an alias. Toss some double quotes around `"FIRST"` if you want to use that as a column name/alias. You'll also need to add the double quotes to `FIRST` in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The error thrown currently (there may be others) is caused by selecting `*` as well as something else. The only way to select "all columns" **and** other things is to give the table an alias in the `from` clause, like this: `from my_table t`, and then use it in the `select` clause like this: `select t.*, ...` Other than that, what do you mean by `from ()`? You surely don't have a table called `()`, so why are you showing that? Do you need help, or not?

Comment: @JNevill, not really. You *can* use `first` as such. It is a **keyword**, but not a **reserved word**.

Comment: My mistake. Must be @Mathguy's excellent catch then :)

Comment: @mathguy - Thankyou Mathguy, yes I need help, I tried the way you suggested but still getting an error, have updated my question for your reference with suggested change and new error encountered.

Comment: The new error suggests that column `begda` represents a date, but in fact the data type is `varchar2` or some other string type, instead of being `date`. If that is the case, you need to use `to_date(begda, <format model>)` with the format model used by that column; and ask "the bosses" to consider fixing this unbelievable mistake - dates must always be stored in `date` data type, not as strings.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this is what you're after.

```
SQL> with
  2  test (id, doj, dol) as
  3  -- sample data
  4    (select 100, sysdate - 10, sysdate + 5 from dual union all
  5     select 200, sysdate     , sysdate - 8 from dual
  6    ),
  7  -- new CTE that counts rows
  8  tcount as
  9    (select t.id, t.doj, t.dol,
 10       count(case when doj <= current_date and (dol is null or dol >= current_date) then id end) first
 11     from test t
 12     group by t.id, t.doj, t.dol
 13    )
 14  -- finally
 15  select *
 16  from tcount
 17  where first = 1;

        ID DOJ                 DOL                      FIRST
---------- ------------------- ------------------- ----------
       100 22.11.2021 19:45:43 07.12.2021 19:45:43          1

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- lines #1 - 5 - sample data; you already have that table and wrongly identified it by `()`
- lines #6 - 10 - selecting rows from the table, along with the `count` function
- finally, select rows for which `count` function returned `1`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, my date format was wrong according to Oracle Syntax,

Below code worked for me,

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(a.begda,'YYYYMMDD'), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```